# How to get task priority

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, ews-managed-api

Is there any way to retrieve the priority of a task using EWS Managed API?

I can't find such a property in the MSDN documentation or intelisense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

get Importance from `Item.Importance`: [Importance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.importance%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx)